# Views Slideshow block not working properly when I add any Sort Criteria

Tags: views

From the fields I added the NID, image, title, body. When I replaced the body with a custom text area field from content type there was a problem:

From the 5 pictures that are in the view, only 1 or 2 show up, others do not show up or simply ignores them and go back to the first image in the slideshow. The problem exists only if I set any Sort Criteria, otherwise everything is working properly.

I cleared the cache, run cron, but without success, the problem still exists.

I forgot to mention, when there is no image, no other fields also.

Comment: when I put the body instead of a text field, everything works as it should...any idea why this is happening?

Comment: now the link is working properly, have you set now to body field ?

Comment: Yes, I just mentioned it in a comment...

Comment: are you using the same content for both body and text field

Comment: No, these are different fields, and both fields are used Full HTML

Comment: try this method, but I'm not sure, rewrite the output of body field and put the text area token there

Comment: I must to hide text area field (to avoid duplication), will it still show through the body?

Comment: check on "exclude the display " for text area field

Comment: I figured out what the problem is. The problem arises when I mark 'Trim this field to a maximum length', I do not have that problem with body field. Any solution for this problem?